# How to automatically change to new line but not hide the contents for long text?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am building an ionic app, for long text, the part of contents are hidden as ... and cannot seen by user. Is it possible to make long text automatically change to new line and show all contents?

[image: ,]

```
 <ion-avatar item-start >
    <img src="assets/img/A_icon.png" style="..."/>
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>Start</h2>
  <p>{{this.startTime}}</p>
  <p>{{this.startAddress}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't clarified but this looks like Ionic 4 code.

The correct way to control this is to use the built in `ion-text-wrap` class:

[CSS Utilities - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#text-modification)

Example:

```
  <ion-avatar item-start >
    <img src="assets/img/A_icon.png" style="..."/>
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>Start</h2>
  <p class="ion-text-wrap">{{this.startTime}}</p>
  <p class="ion-text-wrap">{{this.startAddress}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the ellipse and add `word-break: break-all;`. See the example below.

```css
p {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
}

.break {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.ellipse {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<h2>break</h2>
<p class="break">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

<h2>ellipse...</h2>
<p class="ellipse">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. I add p and .break in scss file as you taught, but it doesn't work.

Comment: you will need to update the OP with the css you are using. The above answer is the generic way, not specific to your issue.